# icon is not working in react native paper text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lib

Code

```
<TextInput
    mode="outlined"
    label="Enter Password"
    outlineColor="#000"
    activeOutlineColor="#0073D9"
    right={<TextInput.Icon name="eye" />}
    style={{
        backgroundColor: '#eee', marginRight: scale(20),
        marginLeft: scale(20),
    }}
    value={Pass}
    onChangeText={(text) => setPass(text)}
/>
```

Output

[image]

How to add an icon in react native paper text input?

Answer (score 1):

add secureTextEntry in TextInput and for more Icons - https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/

```
<TextInput
      label="Password"
      secureTextEntry
      right={<TextInput.Icon icon="eye" />}
    />
```

Comment: it also not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use icon prop instead of name.

your example

```
    <TextInput
    mode="outlined"
    label="Enter Password"
    outlineColor="#000"
    activeOutlineColor="#0073D9"
    right={<TextInput.Icon name="eye" />}
    style={{
        backgroundColor: '#eee', marginRight: scale(20),
        marginLeft: scale(20),
    }}
    value={Pass}
    onChangeText={(text) => setPass(text)}/>
```

the right way:

```
    <TextInput
    mode="outlined"
    label="Enter Password"
    outlineColor="#000"
    activeOutlineColor="#0073D9"
    right={<TextInput.Icon icon="eye" />}
    style={{
        backgroundColor: '#eee', marginRight: scale(20),
        marginLeft: scale(20),
    }}
    value={Pass}
    onChangeText={(text) => setPass(text)}/>
```

and if you want to know what value you could use, here is the source:

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/icons/

I hope this help :)